# Who can gran privileges?

Tags: sql, privileges, sql-grant

I have this question that i didn't find in google:

In SQL only an administrator can grant privileges or is possible to add an user privileges to add privileges and for exmaple: Be an administrator without privilege to grant or revoke other's privileges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the database you're using it's possible to grant priviledges without being administrator.

In PostgreSQL for example you have the "WITH GRANT OPTION" suffix that allows you to grant a priviledge you have to others.

PostgreSQL documentation on this subject:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-grant.html